# Windows 10 and USB remote controls

Tags: windows-10

I have this generic usb remote control that used to work fine under Windows 7.
Now I plugged it on a Windows 10 machine and some keys of it won't work, mainly multimedia keys (next track, volume, ...), just a few keys still works.
I read somewhere that windows 10 really does that to mostly all gerneric usb remotes.

Is there a fix for that? A driver or something?

[image]

Comment: Have you gone to the manufacture's website and checked if there is a Windows 10 device driver for it?  If there is not a Windows 10 device driver for it, your unlikely to get it working, since devices like that normally required it to perform the multi-media functions.

Comment: There is no driver. It is just like a keyboard/mouse.

Comment: I recently bought a similar USB remote that doesn't seem to work at all in Windows 10. No drivers to download anywhere. Awesome.